# ffmpeg apply command on every mp4 file in folder

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, command-line-arguments

I have the command

```
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "${file%.mp4} -vf fps=1/60 img%03d.jpg; done
```

Which I want to use in ffmpeg to iterate over every mp4 file in a directory and run the `ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -vf fps=1/60 img%03d.jpg` command on.  However when I run the above for loop, I get the error "File was unexpected at this time." How can I fix this?

I should also mention that the file names have spaces and other special characters in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

- A closing quote is missing.
- [Parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) is not needed for the input because there is no need to remove any part of the input name, so just use a normal variable.
- Parameter expansion is needed for the output, or else each looped command will make the same output names.
- Outputting the images to their own directory will keep things tidier.
- I added `-q:v 3` to increase the quality of the JPG output. A good range to try is 2-5, where a lower value is a higher quality and larger file size.

Fixed example:

```
mkdir images
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -vf fps=1/60 -q:v 3 "images/${file%.mp4}.jpg"; done
```